# Get Window Service list over network

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to get all windows services that installed on other machine through network

I'm using C#.

This is my code

```
ServiceController[] svDetail = ServiceController.GetServices("192.168.1.2");
```

I have an Exception here. This is Exception message

```
Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer . This operation might require other privileges.
```

How can I get services over network?

Comment: Are you an admin on the remote computer?  Does it work if you use the Services control panel to try to manage services on the remote computer

Comment: Try running `sc \\192.168.1.2 query` from elevated command line.
See if it says `Access is denied`.
Secondly, you can see the exact deny reason in the Windows Event Viewer.